# Compatibility Issues with JQuery Mouse Hover Event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, drop-down-menu

I'm trying to come up with a way to make a drop down box that is displayed through a jquery mouse hover event and with nested dropdown boxes displayed through hovering over elements of the original drop down box. I wrote some terribly inefficient code and I'm struggling to find ways of simplifying it so that I can know why its not working in IE and Firefox. If anyone has any suggestions that will help me get a better idea of whats going on with these compatibility issues, please help.

here is the link:

http://jsfiddle.net/xZNU2/

http://cs-dev.dreamhosters.com/dropd.php

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".tab, .drop").hover(function(){
$(".tab").css("color","#FF7722");
$(".drop").css("display","block");
$("#tv, .droptv").hover(function(){
        $(this).css("color","#FF7722");
        $(".droptv").css("display","block");
        $(".droptv").hover(function(){
                $("#tv, .droptv").css("color","#FF7722");
                },function(){
                $(".droptv").css("color","#005BAB");
                });
        },function(){
        $(this).css("color","#005BAB");
        $(".droptv").css("display","none");
        });
$("#interact").hover(function(){
        $(this).css("color","#FF7722");
        },function(){
        $(this).css("color","#005BAB");
        });
$("#online").hover(function(){
        $(this).css("color","#FF7722");
        },function(){
        $(this).css("color","#005BAB");
        });
$("#vod, .dropvod").hover(function(){
        $(this).css("color","#FF7722");
        $(".dropvod").css("display","block");
        $(".dropvod").hover(function(){
                $("#dai").hover(function(){
                    $(this).css("color","#FF7722");
                    },function(){
                    $(this).css("color","#005BAB");
                    });
                $("#iguide").hover(function(){
                    $(this).css("color","#FF7722");
                    },function(){
                    $(this).css("color","#005BAB");
                    });
                $("#vod").css("color","#FF7722");
                },function(){
                $(".dropvod").css("color","#005BAB");
                });
        },function(){
        $(this).css("color","#005BAB");
        $(".dropvod").css("display","none");
        });
$("#tablet").hover(function(){
        $(this).css("color","#FF7722");
        },function(){
        $(this).css("color","#005BAB");
        });
$("#mobile").hover(function(){
        $(this).css("color","#FF7722");
        },function(){
        $(this).css("color","#005BAB");
        });
},function(){
$(".tab").css("color","#005BAB");
$(".drop").css("display","none");
 });
});
```

Comment: Belongs on: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: If you can show your HTML as well, we might be able to make this MUCH shorter. Also, this is a better fit for codereview..

Comment: there are some serious compatibility issues that result from this code in different browsers. Perhaps a quick edit would justify its existence here?

Comment: @KyleSevenoaks I posted a link to jsfiddle where all my code is. I posted the question phrased differently here http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/19343/simplifying-code-for-drop-down-box-in-jquery-and-html thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your number 1 problem is that you are attaching events on a event e.g:

```
$(".dropvod").hover(function(){
    $("#dai").hover(function(){
        ...
```

It is extremely slow to attach events to DOM elements, not to mention the fact that you will be re-attachig the `$("#dai)` again, and again every time the mouse enters a`.dropvod` element.

My advise is to get a handle of the elements that you want to interact with and use delegated events to updated the elements e.g:

```
/* It would be better to create an association between the elements
 * For example data-index="1" would relate to the hover to the element to show
 */
$('.drop').on('mouseenter', '.dropl', function (e) {
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    $('.drop' + id).show();

}).on('mouseleave', '.dropl', function (e) {
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    $('.drop' + id).hide();

}).on('mouseenter', '.hoverable', function () {
    $(this).css("color","#FF7722");

}).on('mouseleave', '.hoverable', function () {
    $(this).css("color","#005BAB");
});
```

In regards to cross-browser, your code appears to work in FF, I assume that IE is just shitting itself :-)

Answer (score 1):

You should use `<ul> <li>` or `<dl> <dt> <dd>` instead of just div. However, if you'd like to keep it the way it is, you can make it more dynamic by finding all the sub-elements of certain sections something like this: (not actual code)

```
$('dropl').hover(
    function(){$(this).find)('.otherclass').slideDown(300);},
    function(){$(this).find)('.otherclass').slideUp(300);}
);
```

Also, you can be a lot more efficient if you just use css for the color changes on hover like this:

```
.dropl {
    color: #005BAB;
}

.dropl:hover {
    color: #FF7722;
}
```

Do you sort of understand that? You dont need to write all that code, just use different class for the things you want, and jQuery can do stuff with everything in that class.